# Overriding a .class generated from a third party JS snippet to display: none; in a Gatsby JS site

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Overriding a .class generated from a third party JS snippet to display: none; in a Gatsby JS site.

Here is what I have thus far, located in the **gatsby-browser.js** file.

```
export const onClientEntry = () => {
window.onload = () => {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('sc-7dvmpp-1 fprIlH').style.display = 'none';
  });
 };
};
```

The class I wish to override and display: none;

```
<a type="link" href="https://example.com" class="sc-7dvmpp-1 fprIlH">Get Icon</a>
```

Comment: Do you want remove the class or set it to `display: none`?

Comment: @KimSantos looking to set it to display: none. Which I thought my code would do but it's not working. No errors.

Comment: Do you have one or more element with these classes?

Comment: @Zsolt Meszaros just the one

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to that `.sc-7dvmpp-1 .fprIlH` class name to any [SCSS (or CSS)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/global-css/) file, even in [CSS-in-JS](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/css-in-js/). Just create a `.scss` or `.css` file and add:

```
.sc-7dvmpp-1 .fprIlH {
   display: none;
}
```

Import your file using:

```
import "./yourFileName.css"
```

*Note: this assumes that your file is in the same directory as your JavaScript component file. Adapt it to your needs.*

If the class name it's autogenerated and may change the name, use some kind of pseudoselector like:

```
a[class^="sc-"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however the current CSS on those classes is generated by a Third Party API. This won’t override it, which is why I wanted to do it on load.

Comment: Do they have any patterns that could be caught by the CSS? (src of the anchor, initial class name, etc)

Comment: the top level has an ID #gb-widget-5269 which wraps all the html from the api in question.

Comment: You can point to the `#gb` id then and reach the desired children